# How to check if a value is present in a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am using session in my Django Application.

`request.session['permissions']` is structured in the following manner. The key is same for every values. Basically it is a list of dictionaries

```
[{'mykey': 'value1'}, {'mykey': 'value2'}, {'mykey': 'value3'}, 
 {'mykey': 'value4'}, {'mykey': 'value5'}, {'mykey': 'value6'}]
```

```
permissions = request.session['permissions']
```

Now I want to check if `value4` is present inside `permissions`. I am not getting how to check the value.

Whenever I am trying to access value like this

```
permissions.mykey
```

It is giving me error

```
'list' object has no attribute 'mykey'
```

I want to do similar like this

```
permissions = request.session['permissions']
if value not in permissions:
   print('Value is inside list')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it like this using [filter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
permissions = request.session['permissions']
exists = list(filter(lambda x: x.get('mykey') == 'value4', permissions))  # for python 3

# for python2
#  exists = filter(lambda x: x.get('mykey') == 'value4', permissions)

if len(exists) > 0:
   print('value4 exists')
```

Answer (score 3):

use a for loop to get the single dictionary and then check the key

```
for perm in permissions: 
    if value in perm.values():
        print('Value is inside list')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
value_to_check = some_value
permissions = request.session['permissions']
for perm in permissions:
    for key in perm:
        if perm[key] == value_to_check:
           print "Value is present"
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers point out. The issue is that you are trying to use a dictionary accessor on a list object. Since `permissions` is a list of dictionaries you need to check all the dictionaries in the list for the `value4`. This can be done in many ways, in my mind the most pythonic way would be to use list comprehension, something like `[value4 == d for d['mykey'] in permissions]`